# How to impliment below XQuery using cts:element-values

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic, cts-search

I am having below query which is using `cts:search` which is taking lot of time while running in production

```xq
xquery version "1.0-ml";
(: let $limit := ()  use this instead to display all values :)
for $uri in cts:uri-match("/tag-cloud/*")
let $values :=""
let $region := fn:substring-before(fn:substring-after($uri, "/tag-cloud/"), ".xml")
let $doc := concat("/tag-cloud/",$region,".xml")
let $distinct-search-text := cts:search(doc($doc)/All-searchtext/searchtext,
               cts:element-attribute-range-query(xs:QName("searchtext"), xs:QName("date"),
               ">=",
              (fn:current-date() - xs:dayTimeDuration("P2D"))
              )


             )

let $result-xml :=  for $each-search-text in fn:distinct-values($distinct-search-text/text())
                let $count := count($distinct-search-text[text() eq $each-search-text]) 
                order by $count descending
                return 
                fn:concat($region,"&#x09;", $each-search-text, "&#x09;",$count) 


return 
for $eachtag in (($result-xml)[1 to 15])
  return ($eachtag)
```

Can anyone please help me in re-writing above query using `cts:element-values` function because I just need values with frequency.

I tried below query but filtering is not working properly. Any help is much appriciated

```xq
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $limit := 15
(: let $limit := ()  use this instead to display all values :)
for $uri in cts:uri-match("/tag-cloud/*")
let $region := fn:substring-before(fn:substring-after($uri, "/tag-cloud/"), ".xml")
let $values :=
cts:element-values(
  xs:QName("searchtext"),
  "",
  (
    "collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint",
    "item-frequency",
    "frequency-order",
    "descending",
    if (fn:exists($limit)) then fn:concat("limit=", $limit) else ()
  ),
 cts:and-query((
   cts:element-attribute-range-query(xs:QName("searchtext"), xs:QName("date"),
               ">=",
              (fn:current-date() - xs:dayTimeDuration("P2D"))
              ),
 cts:document-query($uri)))
 )
 for $value in $values
 return
   fn:concat($region, "&#x09;", $value, "&#x09;", cts:frequency($value))
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "filtering is not working properly"?

Comment: Please provide a sample tag-cloud xml document, and also explain the functional goal..

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve a document with `doc()`, there's no reason to search.  You already have the document.

Another general point: you should try to build a single search request that does what you want instead of iterating and executing multiple search requests.  For example,instead of iterating over `cts:uri-match()`, consider whether you could perform a single `cts:search()` with a `cts:directory-query()` clause.

For the particularly problem, I'm not sure I understand the goal.  If you create a range index on searchtext, you can calculate frequencies as described in:

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:frequency

If you need those frequencies to reflect the region, one approach would be to build the region into the searchtext values.

But, maybe I misunderstand the goal.

Hoping that's of some help,

Erik Hennum